# CXF not returning bad response when a JsonMappingException occurs

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, cxf

Not sure if the issue is related to CXF or Jackson.

My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyController {    

    @GET
    @Path("test.json")
    public List<TestValue> test() {
        return newArrayList(new TestValue("A"), new TestValue("X"));
    }    

    private static class TestValue {
        private String value;    

        public enum Value {
            A, B, C
        }    

        public TestValue(String v) {
            value = v;
        }    

        public String getValue() {
            return Value.valueOf(value).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this response:

```
❯ curl -v http://localhost:9100/test.json                                                                                                                                                               [18:09:53]
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9100 (#0)
> GET /test.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9100
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 16:09:58 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"value":"A"},{}]<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No enum constant MyController.TestValue.Value.X (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[1]->MyController$TestValue["value"])</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>%
```

Of course the response is wrong, but more importantly I get `200` as status code.

I know it would be much better to get the `Value` instance in the constructor and have the `value` attribute as `Value` and not `String`.
In fact by doing this it works fine, I get a `400` response.

Anyway I would like to be sure that even if misused I don't get a `200` for a request like that.

I'm using:

- `'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.8.8'`
- `'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:3.1.11'`

with `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`.

Is there some CXF or Jackson configuration I'm missing?